# How to implement text wrapping in svgwrite?

Tags: python, svgwrite

I'm using svgwrite in python to generate output based off my Tensorflow model to output simulated handwritten text. My current setup requires an array of strings to represent line breaks however the generated text size isn't consistent and sometimes renders awkward spacing after the last word in the line such as
[image: this]

Is it possible to add text-wrapping to a single long line that would automatically add line breaks when the current line reaches the max width given? A Google Search brought me to the svgwrite page and suggested to use [TextArea](https://svgwrite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes/text.html#textarea) but the examples given are HTML.

```
    def _draw(self, strokes, lines, filename, stroke_colors=None, \
          stroke_widths=None, background_color='white'):

    lines = [
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,",
        "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
        "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris",
        "nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in",
        "reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
    ]

    stroke_colors = stroke_colors or ['black']*len(lines)
    stroke_widths = stroke_widths or [2]*len(lines)

    line_height = 35
    view_width = 152.4
    view_height = 101.6

    dwg = svgwrite.Drawing(filename=filename)
    dwg.viewbox(width=view_width, height=view_height)
    dwg.add(dwg.rect(insert=(0, 0), size=('153mm', '102mm'), fill=background_color))

    for i in range(3):
            
        
        initial_coord = np.array([30,-((i*450)+25)])
        strokesc = self._sample(lines, [1 for i in lines], [7 for i in lines]);
        
        for offsets, line, color, width in zip(strokesc, lines, stroke_colors, stroke_widths):

            if not line:
                initial_coord[1] -= line_height
                continue
            offsets[:, :2] *= random.randint(150, 190)/100
            strokesc = drawing.offsets_to_coords(offsets)
            strokesc = drawing.denoise(strokesc)
            strokesc[:, :2] = drawing.align(strokesc[:, :2])

            strokesc[:, 1] *= -1
            strokesc[:, :2] -= strokesc[:, :2].min() + initial_coord

            prev_eos = 1.0
            p = "M{},{} ".format(0, 0)
            for x, y, eos in zip(*strokesc.T):
                p += '{}{},{} '.format('M' if prev_eos == 1.0 else 'L', x, y)
                prev_eos = eos
            path = svgwrite.path.Path(p)
            path = path.stroke(color=color, width=width, linecap='round').fill("none")
            dwg.add(path)

            initial_coord[1] -= line_height

    dwg.save()
```

This is my current solution in python which outputs the example above

Answer (score 0):

You could try working directly on the text :

```
my_text = sum(lines)
nb_lines = len(lines)


nb_words_per_line = len(my_text.split()) // nb_lines

new_lines = []
cmpt = 0
tmp = ""
for i, word in enumerate(my_text.split()):
    
    if cmpt%nb_words_per_line == 0:
        new_lines.append(tmp)
        tmp = ""
    tmp += word + " "

if tmp:
    new_lines.append(tmp)
```

You can then use `new_lines` as you used `lines` before.

Answer (score 0):

so you simply want to wrap a text with a predefined number of max. characters?
I guess python's native [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) is what you're searching for

> The textwrap module provides some convenience functions, as well as TextWrapper, the class that does all the work. If you’re just wrapping or filling one or two text strings, the convenience functions should be good enough; otherwise, you should use an instance of TextWrapper for efficiency.

```py
import textwrap

lines = [
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,",
    "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris",
    "nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in",
    "reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
]

textwrap.wrap(" ".join(lines), 40)

>>> Out:
>>> ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur',
>>> 'adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor',
>>> 'incididunt ut labore et dolore magna',
>>> 'aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis',
>>> 'nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris',
>>> 'nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.',
>>> 'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit',
>>> 'in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu',
>>> 'fugiat nulla pariatur.']
```

or if you directly want to join the resulting list of strings with newlines:

```py
textwrap.fill(" ".join(lines), 40)
>>> Out:
>>> 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur\nadipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor\nincididunt ut labore et dolore magna\naliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis\nnostrud exercitation ullamco laboris\nnisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\nDuis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit\nin voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu\nfugiat nulla pariatur.'
```

#### update: justification of rendered text:

the "actual" justification of the rendered text is achieved by specifying the "textLength" property (see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TextElementTextLengthAttribute) and [here](https://svgwrite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes/text.html#svgwrite.text.Text) for more details and options).

```
import sys
import svgwrite

import textwrap

lines = [
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,",
    "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris",
    "nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in",
    "reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
]

# wrap text to max. 40 characters
usetext = textwrap.wrap(" ".join(lines), 40)

filename = sys.argv[0].rstrip('.py')

def create_svg(name):
    svg_width = 500
    svg_height = 300

    font_size = 20
    dwg = svgwrite.Drawing(name, (svg_width, svg_height), debug=True)
    # background will be white.
    dwg.add(dwg.rect(insert=(0, 0), size=('100%', '100%'), fill='white'))
    
    for i, line in enumerate(usetext):
        dwg.add(dwg.text(line, insert=(0,  font_size * (i + 4)),
                font_family="serif", font_size=font_size, fill='black',
                textLength=svg_width),
                )
    
    dwg.save()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_svg(filename + '.svg')
```

[image]

Comment: The only thing with this approach is that when the words are processed with the rest of the draw function their vary in size which renders the lines a different length everytime

Comment: yep... but this is a problem of the text-rendering in general.... after all you don't use a mono-spaced font so even if each line would have the same number of characters the lines would have different lengths in the rendered image depending on the font used.   (I'm not familiar with `svgwrite` but maybe it has some options for "justification" of a given multiline text? (e.g. stretching of spaces to achieve the same line-length)

Comment: @TehPirate I've had a quick look at `svgwrite` and updated the answer with a small working example that shows how to actually get text-justification

Comment: Thank  you @raphael ! I appreciate the help and will adapt this into my project. However this would cause words to be cut off on to new lines wouldn't it?

Comment: hey, sorry for not responding (i was on holiday)... I'd not expect words to be cut off (only spaces will be stretched so that the line fits the defined width)    check the links I've provided above for a clear description on the functionalities